# In App Purchase For New App

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In what state does the app have to be in iTunes Connect to allow me to test the in app purchase features? I've tried sending it the codes but it's always invalid. I've checked many of the checklists online and made sure they were completed.

Does the app need to be reviewed (or the in app purchase)? Which "status" do they need to be in in order to be able to test it?

Note: I have waited a couple days and currently both are waiting for review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, review is not required for that.

You can upload it and then reject it immediately.
as long as you can add products in iTunes connect it will be enough for testing.

Comment: Ok, that's what I did the first time. Not sure what is going on then.

Comment: what was the problem? did you use a test user account?

Comment: I am signed out, but never get to the Test User Account cause it never returns any products, both codes are always invalid. Should there be a price tier on the in app purchase? Seems like every time i try to set it it doesn't show up on the details.

Comment: you should set all the data for your products as if you are going to sell it right now. and make sure they are cleared for sale.

Comment: They are definitely cleared for sale, and I've tried many times to set the price tier but when I hit OK it goes away and there is nothing in the table. Is that a bug? http://postimage.org/image/vtoepjns3/

Comment: I think I saw this problem. inside the price tier editing set the dates for "now" and "never" and tap add to schedule. only then tap save.

Comment: I have tried that multiple times (just tried again) but it fails to add it to the table in that view or the one you get when you save.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6303/discussion-between-philippe-sabourin-and-shannoga)